# Retrieving two table values in SQL

Tags: c#, sql

Table r1

```
collegename  subject  position
coll1        english  rao1
coll1        english  rao2
coll1        english  rao3
```

Table r2

```
collegename subject workload  posts
coll1       english   100      3
```

What is the query to display the following.

```
collegename   subject position  workload posts
coll1         english  rao1       100     3
coll1         english  rao2      
coll1         english  rao3
```

Comment: Try using `union` or `join` to combine two tables.

Comment: please make your question more clear

Comment: Are you in the middle of a test that you want us to answer? If not show us what you've tried? Have you tried searching on Joining tables?

Comment: You wat only 1 row to be added in final result??

Answer (score 1):

The code you need is along the lines of:

```
SELECT r1.ColegeName, r1.Subject, r1.Position r2.WorkLoad, r2.Posts
FROM r1
LEFT JOIN r2 ON r1.CollegeName = r2.CollegeName AND r1.Subject = r2.Subject
```

I suggest you read up on Joins; [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) is a good start.